# Does placement of Dispatch Group Enter matter?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Say I want a few asynchronous tasks to complete before running some completion block. I decide to make a function that uses a Dispatch Group to make sure those things get done before continuing, something like this:

```
func doStuff() {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    Do asynchronous task 1 {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    Do asynchronous task 2 {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    } 

}
```

Would the code above behave the exact same as the following code?

```
func doStuff() {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    Do asynchronous task 1 {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    Do asynchronous task 2 {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    } 

}
```

In other words, do I need to put the Dispatch Group enters right next to the task I want to complete or do they work more like a counter where I can just put all of them at the start corresponding to the number of tasks I want to complete?

Comment: They will behave the same as long as the amount of enter() calls matches the amount of leave() calls

Comment: So was I correct in assuming enter() behaves like a counter?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: So are there any advantages to using them instead of counter variable like incrementing 'i' every time a task completes and checking 'if i==2 { completion() }'?

Comment: @MarksCode yes, think about the synchronization ... you have to access your own counter in threadsafe manner